# Setting many values in large matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata

**Problem:** I have a large data.table `dt` with about a million x and y values. These x-y combinations stand for events on a 2-D plane. I know the dimensions of that plane (`iwidth`, `iheight`).

I want to create a matrix that is 0 everywhere except in the x-y value that that are listed in the data.table. At these spots the matrix value should be 1. In general this is easily done, but with a million x-y values to set, regular approaches are not suited.

**Approach:** Since not every x-y combination will be represented in the data.table, I first create a 0-matrix with the right dimensions. Then I replace the 0s at the points indicated by the data.table into 1s.

```r
## initial setup (for easier testing we just use a data.frame, not a data.table)
iwidth = 4288
iheight = 8576
dt = data.frame( xval=sample(iwidth ,10), yval=sample(iheight ,10) )

## simple approach
mx = matrix(ncol=iwidth, nrow=iheight, data=0)
mx[dt$xval, dt$yval] = 1

## biganalytics approach
library(biganalytics)
mx = as.big.matrix(matrix(ncol=iwidth, nrow=iheight, data=0))
mx[dt$xval, dt$yval] = 1
```

**Failure:** For small data this works perfectly fine. However, when you actually have a data.table with a million rows, it takes forever. I thought the `biganalytics` package might help, but this is true only for small data, while it is actually worse with large data (see benchmark below). I also tried `apply` or `with` but for me they did not work either (I think they should be even slower).

These are the microbenchmark results (with n=1) for the above approach (the dt5, dt50, etc. stand for a data.table with 5 rows, 50 rows, etc.). The time it takes increases extremely once we reach long data.tables (i.e. many values to replace in the matrix).

```r
## Regular matrix:
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    dt5  130.8255  130.8255  130.8255  130.8255  130.8255  130.8255     1
   dt50   87.2308   87.2308   87.2308   87.2308   87.2308   87.2308     1
  dt500   86.7591   86.7591   86.7591   86.7591   86.7591   86.7591     1
 dt5000  129.6120  129.6120  129.6120  129.6120  129.6120  129.6120     1
dt50000 4340.6080 4340.6080 4340.6080 4340.6080 4340.6080 4340.6080     1

## Biganalytics matrix:
Unit: milliseconds
   expr          min           lq         mean       median           uq          max neval
    dt5     0.988101     0.988101     0.988101     0.988101     0.988101     0.988101     1
   dt50     0.779401     0.779401     0.779401     0.779401     0.779401     0.779401     1
  dt500     9.814602     9.814602     9.814602     9.814602     9.814602     9.814602     1
 dt5000   202.574901   202.574901   202.574901   202.574901   202.574901   202.574901     1
dt50000 19939.191600 19939.191600 19939.191600 19939.191600 19939.191600 19939.191600     1
```

Comment: is a sparse matrix an option? e.g. `Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = dt$xval, j = dt$yval, x=1, dims=c(iwidth,iheight))`

Comment: When indexing the matrix, `dt$xval` and `dt$yval` should be swapped. `yval` is the rows index and `xval` the columns'.

Comment: thanks a lot @user20650! The sparseMatrix made it possible. I had to write it a little different: `mx=Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = tra$xval+1, j = tra$yval+1, x=1, dims=c(iheight+1,iwidth+1))`. The +1 is necessary for -values in the data.table and the switch of iheight and iwidth is necessary due to what was mentioned in the second comment (thanks a lot for that @RuiBarradas). After that I converted it to a regular matrix with `mx=as.matrix(mx[-1,-1])` (the -1 is there to remove the added row and column from before)

Comment: Couple nitpicky things: you're referring to a `data.table`, but you created a `data.frame`. One of `data.table`'s strengths is speed with large datasets, so it would be helpful to know if that's actually what you're using. Also, maybe your example is simplified from what you're actually working with, but I don't know that a million-row data frame or million-item numeric matrix would on its own constitute "big data." Large enough to think about performance, sure, but so large you need special tools beyond your computer? Not necessarily.

Comment: @camille, thanks for the comment, yes I used a data.frame in the example but in the real world I use a data.table and that still has the same problems (see also the first comment in my first codechunk ;) As to the 'big data' definition, good point, sure one can have much more data than this, but with the PC I use, even 500,000 rows take an insufferable amount of time for this task, plus I will have to write this script for other people's use as well where I don't know what PC power they have. So the amount of data is big enough that I have to pay attention to the methods I employ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Rcpp function might be what you are looking for:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericMatrix 
                  coords_to_matrix(int ncols, int nrows, 
                                   NumericVector x_coords,
                                   NumericVector y_coords) {
                  if(x_coords.size() != y_coords.size()) 
                    stop(\"x_coords and y_coords must be same length\");
                  NumericMatrix m(nrows, ncols);
                  for(int i = 0; i < x_coords.size(); i++)
                  {
                    if((x_coords[i] > ncols - 1) || 
                       (y_coords[i] > nrows - 1)) continue;
                    m[y_coords[i] - 1 + (x_coords[i] - 1) * m.nrow()] = 1;
                  }
                  return m; 
                  }")
```

This seems to do what you need.

For example:

```r
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.frame(x = sample(10), y = sample(10))
dt
#>     x  y
#> 1   9  3
#> 2   4  1
#> 3   7  5
#> 4   1  8
#> 5   2  2
#> 6   5  6
#> 7   3 10
#> 8  10  9
#> 9   6  4
#> 10  8  7

mat <- coords_to_matrix(10, 10, dt$x, dt$y)
mat
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
#>  [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
#>  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
#>  [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
#>  [8,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
#> [10,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

And it seems to run considerably faster than any of your current options:

```r
iwidth = 4288
iheight = 8576
dt5 = data.frame( xval=sample(iwidth ,5), yval=sample(iheight ,5) )
dt50 = data.frame( xval=sample(iwidth ,50), yval=sample(iheight ,50) )
dt500 = data.frame( xval=sample(iwidth ,500), yval=sample(iheight ,500) )
dt5000 = data.frame( xval=sample(iwidth ,5000, replace = TRUE), 
                     yval=sample(iheight ,5000, replace = TRUE) )
dt50000 =  data.frame( xval=sample(iwidth ,50000, replace = TRUE), 
                       yval=sample(iheight ,50000, replace = TRUE) )

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  m5 = m5 <- coords_to_matrix(iwidth, iheight, dt5$xval, dt5$yval),
  m50 = m50 <- coords_to_matrix(iwidth, iheight, dt50$xval, dt50$yval),
  m500 = m500 <- coords_to_matrix(iwidth, iheight, dt500$xval, dt500$yval),
  m5000 = m5000 <- coords_to_matrix(iwidth, iheight, dt5000$xval, dt5000$yval),
  m50000 = m50000 <- coords_to_matrix(iwidth, iheight, dt50000$xval, dt50000$yval),
  times = 10)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>      m5 45.5397 55.2420 105.15879 60.25800  83.0363 284.8644    10   a
#>     m50 45.3205 53.1242 127.77022 58.02275 294.3918 305.8922    10   a
#>    m500 45.3013 45.4073  98.20344 53.51115  55.8047 292.2100    10   a
#>   m5000 45.4192 45.7605  76.51107 54.57740  55.7256 278.7359    10   a
#>  m50000 46.2567 49.4814 104.44953 56.87705  78.4683 302.9901    10   a
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I am going with the sparseMatrix from the comment for convenience sake (easier to write in the script and very fast), but this is actually great also in general for other problems. I'll be sure to expand my horizon with Rcpp ;)